# Why is there a exta 'NONE' output when i enter a negative integer.I only expect 'Plese Enter A Positive Integer 'output

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
def fact(n):
if n<0:
    print('Plese Enter A Positive Integer ')
elif n==0:
    return 1

else:
 return n*fact(n-1)

print(fact(int(input('Plaese Enter The Integer That You Want To Find The Facorial Value'))))
```

Why is there a exta 'NONE' output when i enter a negative integer.I only expect 'Plese Enter A Positive Integer 'output when i input a negative number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its bcos you are saying that print the return value of fact(n).so when n is negative there is no return. so it's printing the return value which is none.To fix this we can use

```
 if n<0:
  return 'Please Enter A Positive Integer '
```